# CSS: Background-image not showing

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

What am I doing bad?

**CSS:**

```css
.submit{
padding-left:10px;
margin:0;
border:0;
outline: 0;
height:32px;
padding-right:32px;
}
.green-btn {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#61A801), to(#8CC400));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
color: #fff;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
border-radius:5px;
}
.clipboard{
background-image: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/opensourceicons/32/Scissors.png) no-repeat right center;
}
​
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Copy" class="submit green-btn clipboard">​
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/77NYA/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot specify the position and repeat values inside the `background-image` property. You can **only** specify the URL to the image. You'll have to separate them out like this:

```css
.clipboard {
    background-image: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/opensourceicons/32/Scissors.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

**Also note:** Some browsers (I don't know which ones) don't allow gradients and background images to be combined together.

---

Here's an alternate solution using a `<button>` with an `<img>` inside it:

```
<button type="submit" value="Copy" class="submit green-btn">
    <img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/opensourceicons/32/Scissors.png" alt="[scissors]" />
    Copy
</button>​
```

```css
.submit{
padding-left:10px;
margin:0;
border:0;
outline: 0;
height:32px;
line-height:32px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.green-btn {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#61A801), to(#8CC400));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #8CC400, #61A801);
color: #fff;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
border-radius:5px;
}
.green-btn img {
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
}​
```

And the [jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/jYmEz/). Feel free to play with the margins and stuff to make it look more how you want.

Comment: I saw that, do you know any character like scissors? Thanks!

Comment: `&#9988;` is ✄ -- don't know how well that dingbat is supported font-wise, it's a fairly high number. You may just have to add an `<img>` to it.

Answer (score 1):

The linear gradient will be overridden by your background-image once you fix the background-image property.

Best way to do this is to create a div and use linear-gradient on it. Create 2 child elements one which will contain text and other which will contain the icon as background. Make the div behave like a submit button using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use background: url(...) instead of background-image

Answer (score 0):

in your .clipboard class remove -image and make it

```
.clipboard { background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/opensourceicons/32/Scissors.png) no-repeat right center;
```

}

because 'no-repeat' is value of background-repeat and 
 and 'right center' is value of background-position, and you are using these values in background-image .

so syntex is background: image-src   repeat-value    image-position